# Quotient rule and chain rule

Tags: calculus

is it possible to use chain rule instead of quotient rule?

Say I have a function as following
$$h(x)=\frac{f(x) }{g(x) } $$
Where $f(x) $ and $g(x) $ are continuous for all $x$ and $g(x) \ne 0$ for all $x$ . 
I want to find $h'(x) $. Is it possible for me to write it as $h'(x) = \frac{d h(x)}{dg(x)} \frac{dg(x)}{dx}  $? Which I use chain rule instead of quotient rule.

Comment: What makes you think that it *should* be possible? This might help us give you a satisfying answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, you can't. You are misunderstanding the meaning of the chain rule.

The product rule is for products, the quotient rule is for quotients, and the chain rule is for compositions. That is, let $f$ and $g$ satisfy necessary hypothesis for the chain rule and let $F(x)=g(f(x))$.

This is a composition of functions, and thus you can use the chain rule to get

$\frac{dF}{dx}=\frac{dg}{df}\cdot\frac{df}{dx}$

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you can if you are able to express $$\frac{f(x)}{g(x)}$$ as two products. Your notation in $h'(x)$ is incorrect though.

$$h'(x) = h(x) \frac{d}{dx}g(x)^{-1} + g(x)^{-1}\frac{d}{dx}h(x)$$

For example let $$ y = \frac{2x}{e^x}$$

For the above, it is clear that you can apply the quotient rule.
However, if you express y as $2xe^{-x}$, you can apply the chain rule here and you should get the same answer. In fact, there are instances where it is easier to differentiate after re-expressing y as two products rather than using the quotient rule.